# Add a column info if same id is find in two table in R

Tags: r, join

I have two tables : One with a selected list of ID and another with all the ID possible.

table one :

| ID | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| AB | row |
| EF | row |
| YZ | row |

table two :

| ID | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| AB | row |
| CD | row |
| EF | row |
| GH | row |
| IJ | row |
| ... | row |
| YZ | row |

I would like to create a label for each ID find in table One with the reference table two.

| ID | Another header | find in table 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | row | yes |
| CD | row | no |
| EF | row | yes |
| GH | row | no |
| IJ | row | no |
| ... | ... | ... |
| YZ | row | yes |

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse) 

table_2 %>% 
  mutate(in_table_1 = if_else(
    ID %in% table_1$ID, "yes", "no"
  ))

# A tibble: 7 × 3
  ID    another in_table_1
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>     
1 AB    row     yes       
2 CD    row     no        
3 EF    row     yes       
4 GH    row     no        
5 IJ    row     no        
6 ...   row     no        
7 YZ    row     yes
```

Comment: I have an error :`Error in `mutate()`:
! Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: @simonbrocard Have you replaced the names `table_1` and `table_2` with the names of your data frames?

Comment: yes with my two data frame